# Describing the quality of a mesh with MeshLab

Tags: meshlab

I am looking for quality indicators for a mesh I have created, and I would like to check things like the smoothness of the shape and the aspect ratio (quality of the triangulation). I have been looking for similar things in the Filters > Quality measures and computations > Per face... and per vertex, but I am not sure which one of them best fits the things I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating the quality of a mesh is a task that strongly depends on what is the purpose of your mesh. For example when using meshes for FEM computations there is an interesting result that shows the equivalence of various criteria for triangular finite element partitions with the well known inscribed and circumscribed ball ratio:

*Brandts, J., Korotov, S., & Krizek, M. (2008). On the equivalence of regularity criteria for triangular and tetrahedral finite element partitions. Computers & Mathematics with Applications, 55(10), 2227-2233. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.camwa.2007.11.010*

Inside MeshLab you can find this metric (and others) inside the filter `Per face quality according to triangle shape and aspect ratio` (to easily find it just type ***shape*** in the search box).

- area/max side of triangle
- ratio inradius/circumradius (radii of incircle and circumcircle)
- Mean ratio of triangle = area/(a*a + b*b + c*c)
- Area
- Texture Angle Distortion. Difference between angle in 3D space and texture space
- Texture Area Distortion. Difference between area in 3D space and texture space
- Polygonal Planarity (max distance to support plane)
- Polygonal Planarity (relative distance to support plane);

The first four metrics are for generic triangular meshes, the last two for evaluating how planar polygonal elements are, and the remaining two metrics are for evaluating the goodness  of texture parametrizations